# Error in obtaining public access token for Mobli

Tags: android, api, mobli

I am having is issues in obtaining the public access token for my app. I am getting the following error:
05-26 14:43:17.194: D/Mobli(1219): Response {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request includes an unsupported parameters","error_uri":"http://dev.mobli.com/error/invalid_request"}

The code that I am using to make the request is as follows:

```
Mobli mobli = new Mobli(ID, SECRET);  
SampleRequestListener mobliListner =  new SampleRequestListener();
runner = new AsyncMobliRunner(mobli);  
runner.obtainPublicToken(mobliListner, null);

public class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListner {
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            // process the response here: executed in background thread
            Log.d("Mobli", "Response " + response.toString());
        } catch (MobliError e) {
            Log.w("Mobli Error", "Error" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
```

Any idea what might be wrong with the code?

I have also verified that the URL is formed correctly. I am getting the filenotfoundexcetion in util.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was as an issue in openUrl function in util.java that is a part of mobli sdk. In the openUrl function an extra parameter was being appended to the post request, which was resulting in the above error. Specifically, commenting out the following lines in openUrl function solved the above issue.

```
// use method override
if (!params.containsKey("method")) {
    params.putString("method", method);
}
```